# Load regex from file and match groups with it in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have a file containing regular expressions, e.g.:

```
City of (.*)
(.*) State
```

Now I want to read these (line by line), match them against a string, and print out the extraction (matched group). For example: The string `City of Berlin` should match with the first expression `City of (.*)` from the file, after that `Berlin` should be extracted.

This is what I've got so far:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @pattern;

open(FILE, "<pattern.txt");   # open the file described above
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    push @pattern, $line;     # store it inside the @pattern variable
}
close(FILE);

my $exampleString = "City of Berlin"; # line that should be matched and
                                      # Berlin should be extracted

foreach my $p (@pattern) { # try each pattern
    if (my ($match) = $exampleString =~ /$p/) {
        print "$match";
    }
}
```

I want `Berlin` to be printed.

- What happens with the regex inside the `foreach` loop?
- Is it not compiled? Why?
- Is there even a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patterns contain a newline character which you need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html):

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    push @pattern, $line;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off - `chomp` is the root of your problem.

However secondly - your code is also very inefficient. Rather than checking patterns in a foreach loop, consider instead compiling a regex in advance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# open ( my $pattern_fh, '<', "pattern.txt" ) or die $!;
my @patterns = <DATA>;
chomp(@patterns);
my $regex = join( '|', @patterns );
$regex = qr/(?:$regex)/;
print "Using regex of: $regex\n";

my $example_str = 'City of Berlin';

if ( my ($match) = $example_str =~ m/$regex/ ) {
    print "Matched: $match\n";
}
```

Why is this better? Well, because it scales more efficiently. With your original algorithm - if I have 100 lines in the patterns file, and 100 lines to check as example str, it means making 10,000 comparisons.

With a single regex, you're making one comparison on each line.

Note - normally you'd use `quotemeta` when reading in regular expressions, which will escape 'meta' characters. We don't want to do this in this case.

If you're looking for even more concise, you can use `map` to avoid needing an intermediate array:

```
my $regex = join( '|', map { chomp; $_ }  <$pattern_fh>  );
$regex = qr/(?:$regex)/;
print "Using regex of: $regex\n";

my $example_str = 'City of Berlin';

if ( my ($match) = $example_str =~ m/$regex/ ) {
    print "Matched: $match\n";
}
```